# How do I slide down a grid with animation on mouse hover in wpf?

Tags: wpf, animation, storyboard

My req is to have a grid of 2 rows - the first row will be filled with comboboxes as search criteria for a DB query. The second row will be a DataGrid with the results.

I want the upper grid to slide down from the top when I hover over it, and slide back up on mouse leave. I guess I can have a simple textblock at the top "Filters" and hovering over it will bring down the comboboxes?

I have something like this, but when mouse over, the animation goes up/down with out stopping.

```
    <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
        <Grid.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation 
                    Storyboard.TargetName="ControlsGrid" 
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Height)"
                    From="0" 
                    To="66" 
                    Duration="0:0:0.5" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation 
                    Storyboard.TargetName="ControlsGrid"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Height)"
                    From="66" 
                    To="0" 
                    Duration="0:0:0.5" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Grid.Triggers>

        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20" Text="Filters..."/>
    </Grid>

    <Grid Margin="0" Name="ControlsGrid" VerticalAlignment="top" Background="Yellow"/>
    <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" ColumnHeaderStyle="{DynamicResource GridViewColumnHeaderStyle}" Background="LightGray" RowBackground="LightYellow" AlternatingRowBackground="LightBlue" 
              x:Name="dataGridViewRoomQuery"  BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="5"/>

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that the "hovering" Grid (the one with the event triggers) gets a `MouseLeave` event whenever the `ControlsGrid` is placed above it.

You have to put the `ControlsGrid` into the hovering Grid:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="0" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ControlsGrid" 
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
                                        To="66" Duration="0:0:0.5" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ControlsGrid" 
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
                                        To="0" Duration="0:0:0.5" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Grid.Triggers>

    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20" Text="Filters..."/>

    <Grid Name="ControlsGrid" Height="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="Yellow">
    </Grid>
</Grid>
<DataGrid .../>
```

Comment: What would i need to do to get the ControlsGrid slide down over the DataGrid, like an overlay? Say height of 400? Putting the DataGrid inside the above grid (above the ControlsGrid) makes it go down right, but the mouse enter triggers everywhere on the whole thing, where it only should trigger on the upper row ("Filters..."). Would it be easier to have a grid with Visible=Collapsed and animate the visibilty?